# How is a live heroku app's custom domain DNS set to default registrar servers?

Tags: heroku, dns

I see in the whois record that the domain of a live heroku hosted site is pointing to the default domain registrar's servers. I would have expected to see the whois record pointing to a DNS service such as Zerigo, for example "a.ns.zerigo.net"

How is it possible that the whois record only shows the registrar's server? Is it through a CNAME setup that the domain name gets to the live site on heroku?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the default domain registrar permits you to edit your domain records then there's no real reason to use another DNS service so you may as well leave the domain there.

Provided you can set www.myapp.com to a CNAME to proxy.heroku.com then all will be fine as this will get the request to Heroku.

Comment: So is it true the DNS entry on the whois record may not provide any insight into where the site is hosted if it has been set via the CNAME mechanism? Thanks

Comment: I think you misunderstand DNS. The DNS entry on whois only shows you which DNS server hosts/controls the domain. Once you know the site, eg www.mysite.com you would do `host www.mysite.com` which would show you the actual host for the entry.